# Counting Occurrences of Values for Keys

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a lot of documents with many attributes. After a specific `$match` pass, I end up with a subsection. Here it is simplified:

```
[
    {"name": "foo", "code": "bbb"},
    {"name": "foo", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "foo", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "foo", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "bar", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "bar", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "bar", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "baz", "code": "aaa"},
    {"name": "baz", "code": "aaa"}
]
```

I would like to count the occurances of certain attributes so I end up with this (simplified):

```
{
    "name": {
        "foo": 4, 
        "bar": 3,
        "baz": 2
    },
    "code": {
        "bbb": 1,
        "aaa": 8
    }
}
```

(Or something close that I can 'translate' afterwards with Node.js)

I already do a `$group` stage to count other attributes (differently). Ideally I would `$addToSet` and also count how many times a similar value was added to the set. But I cannot figure out how.

Alternatively I was thinking to `$push` to end up with this (simplified):

```
{
    "name": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "baz", "baz"],
    "code": ["bbb", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", ]
}
```

But I can't figure out how to turn it into (something close to) the above hypothetical result either.

For single fields alone, the closest I can come is by using the above `$push` and then I can use `$group`:

```
"$group": {
    "_id": {"_id": "$_id", "name": "$name"},
    "nameCount": {"$sum": 1}
}
```

Now I have `_id.name` and `nameCount`. But I have lost all the previously counted attributes, 20 or so.

Is there a way to do (something close to) what I want?

> **Note:** Using MongoDB 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MongoDB 3.2 you are pretty much limited to mapReduce if you want to return the "data" values as "keys" in a returned document. There is however the case to consider that you actually "do not need" MongoDB to do that part for you. But to consider the approaches:

### Map Reduce

```
db.stuff.mapReduce(
  function() { 
    emit(null, {
     name: { [this.name]: 1 },
     code: { [this.code]: 1 }
    })
   },
  function(key,values) {
     let obj = { name: {}, code: {} };
     values.forEach(value => {
       ['name','code'].forEach(key => {
         Object.keys(value[key]).forEach(k => {
           if (!obj[key].hasOwnProperty(k))
             obj[key][k] = 0;
           obj[key][k] += value[key][k];
         })    
       })
     });
     return obj;    
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Returns:

```
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "value" : {
            "name" : {
                "foo" : 4.0,
                "bar" : 3.0,
                "baz" : 2.0
            },
            "code" : {
                "bbb" : 1.0,
                "aaa" : 8.0
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### Aggregate

For MongoDB 3.4 and upwards, you can use `$arrayToObject` to reshape as "key/value" objects. And a bit more efficiently than simply using `$push` to make two large arrays which would almost certainly break the BSON limit in real world cases.

This "more or less" mirrors the `mapReduce()` operations:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "data": [
      { "k": "name", "v": { "k": "$name", "count": 1 } },
      { "k": "code", "v": { "k": "$code", "count": 1 } }
    ]
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "k": "$data.k",  "v": "$data.v.k" },
    "count": { "$sum": "$data.v.count" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.k",
    "v": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.v", "v": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }  
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "in": { 
            "k": "$$this.k",
            "v": { "$arrayToObject": "$$this.v" }
          }
        }    
      }
    }  
  }}
])
```

Which has similar output ( without forcing ordering of keys by applying `$sort` ):

```
{
    "code" : {
        "bbb" : 1.0,
        "aaa" : 8.0
    },
    "name" : {
        "baz" : 2.0,
        "foo" : 4.0,
        "bar" : 3.0
    }
}
```

So it's only really in the final stage where we actually use the new features, and the output up to that point is pretty similar, and would be easy to reshape in code:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "code",
            "v" : [ 
                {
                    "k" : "bbb",
                    "v" : 1.0
                }, 
                {
                    "k" : "aaa",
                    "v" : 8.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "name",
            "v" : [ 
                {
                    "k" : "baz",
                    "v" : 2.0
                }, 
                {
                    "k" : "foo",
                    "v" : 4.0
                }, 
                {
                    "k" : "bar",
                    "v" : 3.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So in fact we can do just that:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "data": [
      { "k": "name", "v": { "k": "$name", "count": 1 } },
      { "k": "code", "v": { "k": "$code", "count": 1 } }
    ]
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "k": "$data.k",  "v": "$data.v.k" },
    "count": { "$sum": "$data.v.count" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.k",
    "v": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.v", "v": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }  
  }},
  /*
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "in": { 
            "k": "$$this.k",
            "v": { "$arrayToObject": "$$this.v" }
          }
        }    
      }
    }  
  }}
  */
]).map( doc =>
  doc.data.map( d => ({
     k: d.k,
     v: d.v.reduce((acc,curr) => 
      Object.assign(acc,{ [curr.k]: curr.v })
      ,{}
     )
  })).reduce((acc,curr) => 
    Object.assign(acc,{ [curr.k]: curr.v })
    ,{}
  )
)
```

Which just goes to show that simply because the aggregation framework does not have the features to use "named keys" in output for earlier versions, you generally do not need them. Since the only place we actually used the new features was in the "final" stage, but we can easily do the same by simply reshaping the final output in client code.

And of course, it's the same result:

```
[
    {
        "code" : {
            "bbb" : 1.0,
            "aaa" : 8.0
        },
        "name" : {
            "baz" : 2.0,
            "foo" : 4.0,
            "bar" : 3.0
        }
    }
]
```

So it helps to learn the lesson of exactly "where" you actually **need** to apply such transformations. Here it's at the "end" since we do not need that during any "aggregation" stage, and thus you simply reshape the results that can be optimally provided from the aggregation framework itself.

---

### The Bad Ways

As noted, your attempt so far may be fine for small data, but in most real world cases "pushing" all the items in a collection into a single document without reduction is going to break the 16MB BSON Limit.

Where it would actually stay under, then you can use something like this monster with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/):

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "name": { "$push": "$name" },
    "code": { "$push": "$code" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { 
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": [
            { "k": "name", "v": "$name" },
            { "k": "code", "v": "$code" }
          ],
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$m.k",
            "v": {
              "$arrayToObject": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$$m.v",
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { 
                        "$in": [
                          "$$this",
                          { "$map": {
                            "input": "$$value",
                            "as": "v",
                            "in": "$$v.k"
                          }}
                        ]
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "$concatArrays": [
                          { "$filter": {
                            "input": "$$value",
                            "as": "v",
                            "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$v.k", "$$this" ] }
                          }},
                          [{
                            "k": "$$this",
                            "v": {
                              "$sum": [
                                { "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  "$$value.v",
                                  { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$value.k", "$$this" ] }
                                ]},
                                1
                              ]
                            }    
                          }]
                        ]    
                      },
                      "else": {
                        "$concatArrays": [
                          "$$value",
                          [{ "k": "$$this", "v": 1 }]
                        ]    
                      }
                    } 
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which produces:

```
{
    "name" : {
        "foo" : 4.0,
        "bar" : 3.0,
        "baz" : 2.0
    },
    "code" : {
        "bbb" : 1.0,
        "aaa" : 8.0
    }
}
```

Or indeed the same reduction process in client code:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "name": { "$push": "$name" },
    "code": { "$push": "$code" }
  }},
]).map( doc => 
  ["name","code"].reduce((acc,curr) =>
    Object.assign(
      acc,
      { [curr]: doc[curr].reduce((acc,curr) =>
          Object.assign(acc,
            (acc.hasOwnProperty(curr))
              ? { [curr]: acc[curr] += 1 }
              : { [curr]: 1 }
          ),{}
        )
      }
    ),
    {}
  )
)
```

Which again has the same result:

```
{
    "name" : {
        "foo" : 4.0,
        "bar" : 3.0,
        "baz" : 2.0
    },
    "code" : {
        "bbb" : 1.0,
        "aaa" : 8.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is invaluable, and I will study it closely. Please don't remove any part of it. However, as a result from my human limitations, I forgot to mention that the initial set of documents is obtained with a `$match` and the resulting collection needs to be counted. I'm guessing __Map Reduce__ is off the table this way. I'm also limited by the SLA restrictions of using MongoDB 3.2, or I would have a blast with `$arrayToObject` and `$replaceRoot`.

Comment: You are correct that my attempt is bad. The first `$match` stage happens on the fly based on user input and returns any set between 1 and 50000 documents. I'm doing something similar to your bottom-most "bad" example. It works with test data, but I know this is not sustainable for the final product.

Comment: I like how you commented out the `$replaceRoot` for illustrative purposes. I will study this part of your answer more to see if it works. Because the initial `$group` already contains a handful of `$sum` counts, but I can't do that if I need to start with a `$project`. I have to find a way to do both in a single pass. And in the end repease all attributes in `$group` using `$first`.

Comment: @Redsandro Well the larger body essentially says that you do not actually need the new features at all, since the "transformation" part of the results can always be done "after" the actual aggregation part is complete. Also [`mapReduce` does have a "query" option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/), which is essentially the same as `$match`. But as a wider point, this answer addressees "the question you asked", and therefore any considerations to other data "outside of the scope of the question" is really not a concern of this answer.

Comment: Definitely upvoted. I was still in the process of reading and commenting. I did however mention I already have a `$group` stage for other counts. Obviously I want to bring them to the end result as well. This is a complication that adds to the puzzle. I will wait for other input before I accept your answer, as recommended: _"A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer."_

Comment: @Redsandro That's not a sentiment I generally agree with, and could point to many occasions where I spot an answered question and believe there could be a "better" answer and simply supply one. But if you want to hang out for a "better answer", then good luck with that.